# Formula to check if all non-empty columns have a particular value

Tags: excel-formula

Like in title: I need to check if the columns have a value='bob' if they are not empty.
If all columns have the value 'bob' then return true.

```
 |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
1| bob | bob |     |     | - should return true
2| bob |     | bob | bob | - should return true
3| bob | tom |     | bob | - should return false
```

Can anyone help me with the formula for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is my try:

In Cell `E1`, enter the following formula and drag it down.

```
=(COLUMNS(A1:D1)-COUNTIFS(A1:D1,"bob")=COUNTBLANK(A1:D1))
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

With the newest version of Excel, try: `=IF(CONCAT(UNIQUE($A1:$D1,1))="Bob", TRUE)`

EDIT:
As pointed out by Terry W, this won't work in cases where non-blank cells sequentially contain "Bob", so a more accurate approach might instead be

`=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF($A1:$D1, "Bob")/COUNTA($A1:$D1)=1, TRUE), FALSE)`

Comment: a good answer, only in extreme circumstance it may not work such as {"b","ob","",""}

Comment: Nice catch, would not have thought of that